# Using ValueQuery gives error

Tags: frame

Storage:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn voting)]
pub type Voting<T: Config> =
StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, Voter<T::AccountId>, ValueQuery>;
```

Type:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Clone, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub struct Voter<AccountId> {
    pub votes: Vec<AccountId>,
    pub score: u128,
}
```

Without ValueQuery it does not give error, but with ValueQuery it gives error, how to fix the error. Seems I need to implement default, not sure how to do it.

```
the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `types::Voter<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ValueQuery` then yes, you need to implement the `Default` trait for your structure if you want to return anything in case the key is missing. I think this should work fine (not sure 100%):

```rs
impl<AccountId> Default for Voter<AccountId> {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Self { votes: Default::default(), score: Default::default() }
  }
}
```

You can always set the `Default::default()` values for a different one in case you want to return something different, the votes can be initialized with some accounts and the score can be any number.

If you omit `ValueQuery`, when interacting with you structure you will get `Option<Voter<AccountId>>`, which means, if you try to get some value from your `StorageMap` you will get either `Some(Voter)` or `None`. Using `ValueQuery` will always return a value, so you don't have to deal with unwrapping the `get` calls.

Hope it helps.